# Which specs of JSF used PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING_METHOD?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jsf-1.2, myfaces

Source code of `MyFaces` (branch 1.1.8) has usage of context parameter `PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING_METHOD` in [NavigationHandlerImpl.java](https://github.com/apache/myfaces/blob/1_1_8/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/application/NavigationHandlerImpl.java) .

Also `NavigationHandlerImpl.java` has comment `//Specs 10.1.3: default server saving` on 82 line.

- Which of specs they talking about and where i can download it? Can't find specs for JSF 1.1.
- Why this context parameter disappeared from next implementations?

This is `PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING` behaviour or `STATE_SAVING_METHOD`? 
Variable declaration on line 66 confuse a bit... (stateSavingMethod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you mention belongs to the very early attempts of PSS technique added in JSF 2. There is no relationship with the spec. Please update to a recent version of Apache MyFaces (2.1, 2.2)